# using sql join to get the sum of data from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below two queries that I want to combine

```
SELECT 
    Order_Header.Order_ID, Order_Header.OrderNumber,
    ISNULL(SUM(SplitValue / CostCentre_CCYRate), 0) AS NetPrice_CCY,Issued_Date
FROM 
    Order_Header
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Order_CostCentre ON Order_Header.Order_ID = Order_CostCentre.Order_ID
WHERE 
    Order_CostCentre.CostCentre_ID = 3093
    AND Order_Header.Issued_Date BETWEEN 'start date' AND 'end date'
    AND Order_Header.Order_Status IN ('ISSUED', 'PARTIAL', 'RECEIVED', 'CLOSED')
GROUP BY 
    Order_Header.Order_ID


SELECT 
    Expense_Header.Expense_ID, Expense_Header.Exp_Number,
    ISNULL(SUM(SplitValue / CostCentre_CCYRate), 0) AS NetPrice_CCY,
    Exp_Date
FROM
    Expense_Header
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Order_CostCentre ON Expense_Header.CostCentre_ID = Order_CostCentre.CostCentre_ID
WHERE 
    Order_CostCentre.CostCentre_ID = 3093
    AND Expense_Header.Exp_Date BETWEEN 'start date' AND 'end date'
    AND Expense_Header.Exp_Status IN ('ACCOUNTS_REVIEW', 'REIMBURSED')
GROUP BY 
    Expense_Header.Expense_ID
```

I want to combine both of them such that I get the sum of the values from both the tables, based on only the `Order_CostCentre.CostCentre_ID`. Please help me in making the query. Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to do about the order number/expense number?  How should those be aggregated together?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen actually all the records should be sum up based on Order_CostCentre.CostCentre_ID, so its ok if I only take order number, I can exclude the expense number

Answer (score 0):

One option is to `UNION` together your two current queries in a subquery, and then select the sum of the net price, grouping by the order ID.  Note that I put each of the two original queries into separate CTEs for readability and maybe even performance.

```
;WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT t1.Order_ID,
           t1.OrderNumber, 
           ISNULL(SUM(SplitValue/CostCentre_CCYRate), 0) AS NetPrice_CCY,
           Issued_Date 
    FROM Order_Header t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Order_CostCentre t2
        ON t1.Order_ID = t2.Order_ID 
    WHERE t2.CostCentre_ID = 3093 AND
          t1.Issued_Date BETWEEN 'start date' AND 'end date' AND
          t1.Order_Status IN ('ISSUED', 'PARTIAL', 'RECEIVED', 'CLOSED')  
    GROUP BY t1.Order_ID
),

WITH cte2 AS (
    SELECT t1.Expense_ID,
           t1.Exp_Number,     
           ISNULL(SUM(SplitValue/CostCentre_CCYRate), 0) AS NetPrice_CCY,
           Exp_Date
    FROM Expense_Header t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Order_CostCentre t2
        ON t1.CostCentre_ID = t2.CostCentre_ID
    WHERE t2.CostCentre_ID = 3093 AND
          t1.Exp_Date BETWEEN 'start date' AND 'end date' AND
          t1.Exp_Status IN ('ACCOUNTS_REVIEW', 'REIMBURSED')
    GROUP BY t1.Expense_ID
)

SELECT t.Order_ID,
       SUM(t.NetPrice_CCY) AS NetPrice_CCY_Total
FROM
(
    SELECT Order_ID, NetPrice_CCY
    FROM cte1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Expense_ID, NetPrice_CCY
    FROM cte2
) t
GROUP BY t.Order_ID
```

Comment: I am getting this error: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.`

Comment: @sumedha Put a comma in between the two CTEs.

Comment: Try using `;WITH cte1 AS (...)` , in other words, listen to the error message and terminate the preceding statement with a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Here your query.try this it may be helpful for you.

```
;with merged_data as (

select Order_ID,NetPrice_CCY from(
SELECT Order_Header.Order_ID,Order_Header.OrderNumber,
IsNull(Sum(SplitValue / CostCentre_CCYRate), 0) AS NetPrice_CCY,Issued_Date
FROM Order_Header
LEFT OUTER JOIN Order_CostCentre ON Order_Header.Order_ID = Order_CostCentre.Order_ID
WHERE Order_CostCentre.CostCentre_ID = 3093
AND Order_Header.Issued_Date BETWEEN 'start date' AND 'end date'
AND Order_Header.Order_Status IN ('ISSUED','PARTIAL','RECEIVED','CLOSED')
GROUP BY Order_Header.Order_ID
) as a

union all

select Expense_ID as Order_ID ,NetPrice_CCY from (

SELECT Expense_Header.Expense_ID,Expense_Header.Exp_Number,
IsNull(Sum(SplitValue / CostCentre_CCYRate), 0) AS NetPrice_CCY,Exp_Date
FROM Expense_Header
LEFT OUTER JOIN Order_CostCentre ON Expense_Header.CostCentre_ID = Order_CostCentre.CostCentre_ID
WHERE Order_CostCentre.CostCentre_ID = 3093
AND Expense_Header.Exp_Date BETWEEN 'start date'    AND 'end date'
AND Expense_Header.Exp_Status IN ('ACCOUNTS_REVIEW','REIMBURSED')
GROUP BY Expense_Header.Expense_ID

) as b
) 
select Order_ID ,sum(NetPrice_CCY) from merged_data
group by Order_ID
```